# New oil vs old oil

Tags: olive-oil

I have two largish containers of extra virgin olive oil. One is ~5 months old, the other is ~17 months old.

Any way to distinguish which is which?

Comment: did you give them a taste?

Comment: If sold commercially I would expect them to have a best before date printed on them. I've only grown a handful of olives in my life (and ate those) but when home-making jams etc. I label with the date of production.  Unfortunately traces of oil can affect labelling

Comment: @Chris H They are not commercial, but neither do they have dates on them.

Comment: @moscafj Just did. Oil A feels a bit bitter, oil B feels somehow "lighter" than A, and not bitter.

Comment: Are the two bottles of oil from the same source?

Comment: @FuzzyChef Same field, different year

Answer (score 1):

"Unlike wine, olive oil does NOT improve with age. As olive oil gets older, it gradually breaks down, the acidity level rises, and flavor weakens. Extra virgin olive oil keeps better because it starts with a low acidity level, but it should ideally be consumed within 18-24 months of harvest."

https://www.oldtownoil.com/blogs/frequently-asked-questions/does-olive-oil-improve-with-age

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This sounds like the beginning of an answer, but you need to edit it so it addresses the question asked. How can you use this information to tell the difference?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So… if it becomes more acidic, litmus paper?

Comment: @Joe Litmus paper simply gives you a binary (red=acidic or blue=alkaline) result; so unless the ageing happened to bring the acidity level across that line, it wouldn't tell you might. I'd suggest something like universal indicator paper, which has a wide range of colours that can (approximately) identify a wide range of pH values.

Comment: @gidds : no, it changes different colors depending on the pH, but it might not be significantly different enough to tell by eye